# Making different registration forms in Django?

Tags: django, abstractuser

I'm trying to create two different types of users in Django using AbstractUser. I've created two models that inherit from my AbstractUser model.

How do I update the UserCreationForm so that it has a field for user type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the built-in UserCreationForm and adjust the fields as necessary.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('type',)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. By 'type', is this where I would include the names of my models that inherit from AbstractUser?

Comment: Yeah you'd just be appending another field_name to the tuple of fields in the UserCreationForm:  `fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('user_type',)`.

Comment: No worries! If you could mark as answer, that would be awesome!

Comment: new to stackoverflow! I missed that the first time. just marked it.